# Circle Least Squares Fit

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So my question is this: 
Find the equation of the circle that gives the best least squares circle fit to the points $(-1,-2), (0,2.4), (1.1,-4),$ and $(2.4,-1.6).$

So far I have this general equation:
$2xc_1+2yc_2+(r^2-c_1^2-c_2^2)=x^2+y^2$ where $r^2-c_1^2-c_2^2 = c_3$

So then I think I create matrix:
$\begin{pmatrix} 2x_1 & 2y_1 & 1 \\ . & . & . \\ 2x_n & 2y_n & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \\ c_3\end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} x_1^2+y_1^2 \\ ... \\ x_n^2+y_n^2\end{pmatrix}$

and after replacing $x_1 = -1$ and $y_1 = -2$ until $x_4$ and $y_4$, I have this matrix:
$\begin{pmatrix} -2 & -4 & 1 \\ 0 & 4.8 & 1 \\ 2.2 & -8 & 1 \\ 4.8 & -3.2 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \\ c_3\end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ 5.76 \\ 17.21 \\ 8.32\end{pmatrix}$

Which i guess I try to solve by setting equal to 0, then moving the last matrix to the other side and make it look like this:
$\begin{pmatrix} -2 & -4 & 1 \\ 0 & 4.8 & 1 \\ 2.2 & -8 & 1 \\ 4.8 & -3.2 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \\ c_3\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ 5.76 \\ 17.21 \\ 8.32\end{pmatrix}$

And finally solve for $c_1$, $c_2$, $c_3$. But this system has no solution as shown [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20%7B%7B-2,-4,1%7D,%7B0,4.8,1%7D,%7B2.2,-8,1%7D,%7B4.8,-3.2,1%7D%7D%7B%7Bc_1%7D,%7Bc_2%7D,%7Bc_3%7D%7D=%7B%7B5%7D,%7B5.76%7D,%7B17.21%7D,%7B8.32%7D%7D). Am I missing something huge here or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Already, you have asked to find the best least square fit. So, what you have is an overdetermined system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just multiply both sides of the equation by $A^{T}\,,$ where $A$ is your matrix, and then solve the resulting system.

Comment: @MhnenniBenghorbal I actually just figured it out on my own but yep that is how to do it. Thanks

Comment: @CharlieYabben: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that the given equation $Ac = B$ has no solution. That is why we are trying to get an approximate answer (least-squares fit).

[An explanation on Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/alternate-bases/orthogonal-projections/v/linear-algebra-least-squares-approximation)
will give you an understanding of the result after approximating it.
If we cannot find the solution to $Ac = B$, we find solution to  $A^TAc=A^TB$.
This equation is the connection missing.